# Python-passing object as an argument of function

Tags: python, object, dll, ctypes

1. There is a function from a DLL (C language) `link("parameters", &connection);`
   which takes a string parameter and initializes a connection.
2. There is a function `connect(connection)`, where the connection - the object, initialized with a call to `link()`.

Question: how to pass Python connection object function Connect () as an argument?

```
from ctypes import *
mydll = CDLL (link.dll)
# How define the connection object?
top = link ("localhost: 5412", connection)
top = connect (connection)
```

Comment: What is the type of the connection parameter in C?

Comment: connection it's winapi HANDLE to object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that winapi handle is 32 bits long, but you might need to ensure that it be that the true length. If you are not using *connection* in any other way, maybe you can do this:

```
connection_t = ctypes.c_uint32

link = mydll.link
link.argtypes=(ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.POINTER(connection_t) )
connect = mydll.connect
connect.argtypes=(connection_t,)
...
connection = connection_t()
link ("localhost: 5412", ctypes.byref(connection))
...
```

Note that:

- You might use another type as the opaque equivalent to HANDLE, as long as it has the same byte-length. Even better, you can "protect" your created *connection*_t type by inheriting instead of just assigning.